# Httprouter trouble with static files

Tags: go

I'm using a router ([httprouter](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter)) and would like to serve static files from root.

*css file in*

`static/style.css`

*in template*

`<link href="./static/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`

*main.go*

```
router := httprouter.New()
router.ServeFiles("/static/*filepath", http.Dir("/static/"))
router.GET("/", Index)
```

But http://localhost:3001/static/style.css gives me an 404 error and style in render page doesn't work too.

Comment: Omit the trailing slash in "/static/"? Other than that, you could try adding some Printfs into the router module to see what's going on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35630260/serving-static-css-and-java-script-while-using-parameters-in-golang-using-github

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to replace `http.Dir("/static/")` with `http.Dir("static")` (which will be the relative path to your static dir) or with `http.Dir("/absolute/path/to/static")`. Your example with this single change works for me.

Also see httprouter's ServeFiles documentation:

> [func (r *Router) ServeFiles(path string, root http.FileSystem)](http://godoc.org/github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter#Router.ServeFiles)
>
> ServeFiles serves files from the given file system root. The path must   end with "/*filepath", files are then served from the local path /defined/root/dir/*filepath. For example if root is "/etc" and *filepath is "passwd", the local file "/etc/passwd" would be served. Internally a http.FileServer is used, therefore http.NotFound is used instead of the Router's NotFound handler. To use the operating system's file system implementation, use http.Dir:
>
> router.ServeFiles("/src/*filepath", http.Dir("/var/www"))

This might also be of help - [Third-party router and static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849844/third-party-router-and-static-files)

I must admit that it's unclear to me why 'static' is needed twice. If I set http.Dir to "." it all works with the single difference that I need to navigate to localhost:3001/static/static/style.css

Answer (score 2):

In call `router.ServeFiles("/static/*filepath", http.Dir("/static/"))` second argument provide root and first arg define the path **from that root**. So , try

```
router.ServeFiles("*filepath", http.Dir("/static"))
```

without mentioning */static/* twice.

Comment: `panic: path must end with /*filepath in path '*filepath'` if "/*filepath" than `panic: path segment '/' conflicts with existing wildcard '/*filepath' in path '/'`

Comment: Can you try router.ServeFiles("static/*filepath", http.Dir("/")) or  maybe router.ServeFiles("/static/*filepath", http.Dir("")) to be more coherent with template. Any way don't mention /static/ twice because /reminder/path appends with  /root

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it working:

```
func main() {
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/", Index)
    router.ServeFiles("/static/*filepath",http.Dir("static"))

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3001", router))
}
```